# Rounding only specific entries of torch.tensor()

Tags: pytorch

Using `torch.round()` is it possible to eventually round specific entries of a tensor? Example:

```
tensor([ 8.5040e+00,  7.3818e+01,  5.2922e+00, -1.8912e-01,  5.4389e-01,
        -3.6032e-03,  4.5763e-01, -2.7471e-02])
```

Desired output:

```
tensor([ 9.,  74.,  5., 0.,  5.4389e-01,
        -3.6032e-03,  4.5763e-01, -2.7471e-02])
```

(Only first 4 rounded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do as follow

```
a[:4]=torch.round(a[:4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (a little bit shorter) option is

```
t = torch.tensor([ 8.5040e+00,  7.3818e+01,  5.2922e+00, -1.8912e-01,  5.4389e-01, -3.6032e-03,  4.5763e-01, -2.7471e-02])

t[:4].round()
```

or inplace

```
t[:4].round_()
```